# A dead body floats with its head immersing in water . Why?

Tags: pressure, biophysics, density, buoyancy

I found this question in my practice book . I want to know about it .

Comment: You should show your attempt to solve the question. You will get little attention and probably no answers with a poorly stated question.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it's more of a bio question. https://www.google.com/search?q=why+do+dead+people+float&oq=why+do+dead+people+float&aqs=chrome..69i57.6523j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

As for the head part, your head (mainly your brain) is more dense than water.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the centre of buoyancy and centre of gravity don't necessarily lie on the same point. This creates two types of mechanical equilibrium: stable and unstable.

It turns out that when a human body is floating with its face inside the water, the body is in stable equilibrium. That is because in that position, the centre of gravity lies below centre of buoyancy.